# Get Sum File Size until File Size < 1000KB - Windows Batch Script

Tags: file, for-loop, batch-file, size

I have a directory where I have a number of CSV files.

I need a loop that loops through the these files, get the file size, gets the total file size looped through so far (So it gets the sum of all the file sizes got since then).

So far I have the below code.

```
SET MY_DIRECTORY=C:\temp
set outsize=0
for %%S in ("%MY_DIRECTORY%\*.csv") do (
    echo. %%S
    echo. %%~zS
    set /a "outsize=%outsize%+%%~zS"
)
echo %outsize%
```

My issue is it's not getting the sum. %outside% only displays the last file size value.

Any idea how to proceed here using just batch?

Right now the only solution that's popping in my head is to just write the file details to a text file outside then just loop through that again but there has to be a better way right?

Comment: Ah.... ok TIL about SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION. After some looking around I found out how For Loops actually work in Batch.

Comment: You don't need Delayed Expansion _in this case_. Just use `set /a "outsize+=%%~zS"`